# Не могу нормально смержить JSON

Tags: json, totalcommander

Добрый день!

Битый час не могу справится с проблемой сравнения двух файлов. Слева исходный файл, справа тот который правлю. В правом JSON добавляю параметр `"get_all": 1,` по всему файлу и при попытке сравнить, везде показываются корректные данные. А именно в этом месте, при добавлении `"get_all": 1,` сравнение сходит с ума, и показывает, что изменилось все, хотя видно что это не так.

В чем может быть проблема, сравниваю в Total Commander, раньше проблем не было. И очень не хочется свернуть все на "ошибку" тотала, а в итоге залить ошибку в рабочий проект

Заранее спасибо за советы и помощь!

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/21532722406a6a298d8fd65fd3e5056e.png]

Comment: попробуйте использовать diff

Comment: диф учитывает пробелы, а я изменял табуляцию, и вообще мрак получается =(

Comment: там есть ключи - `-b`, `-w`